# Hight Chart Polar Scatter Plot values on chart and x-axis

Tags: javascript, angular, charts, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I want to create chart as per below image. I have also created jsfiddle using highchart in the fiddle.
but, still not able to do what I want. How do I do? Any help would be 
    appreciated.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/shahrishabhptechnical/2uxq7raf/

```
jsfiddle - Highcharts Example
```

Comment: Hello Rishabh Shah, Could you describe exactly what the problem is?

Comment: The problem is that I need to show values on x-axis like 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. 
Also, show elips on chart.

Comment: I have also created another jsfiddle using http://jsfiddle.net/shahrishabhptechnical/c9sbgh6o/ using startAngle. In this case, It is showing 0 at y-axis where I need to show at x-axis.
Let me know, if you need any input.

Comment: @ppotaczek- are you doing any change in fiddle?
Thanks
I am also not sure based on given image, will given data structure in the series support this chart? Can you please guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use basic yAxis to show ticks with labels, but you will need the right properties and wrap on `getMarkPath` method:

```
yAxis: {
    lineWidth: 1,
    tickPosition: 'inside',
    showLastLabel: true,
    tickWidth: 1,
    tickColor: '#000000',
    angle: 90,
    tickInterval: 1,
    labels: {
        y: -10
    },
    lineColor: '#000000'
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e940tvzx/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: any idea about showing ellipse on the chart as per image?
My fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/shahrishabhptechnical/2uxq7raf/
I tried using http://jsfiddle.net/arybalko/rcct2r0b/ but, does not work.

Comment: Hi Pratik Rawlekar, yes, to show this ellipse use `SVGRenderer` like now, but with right coordinates: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/kg5nLzpq/